# failed to commit with Intellij Idea svn

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, commit

It was failed to commit the changes to SVN resp while i use the IDEA.
It's so weird that the other functions(like `update`, `merge`) except `commit` works well and no such problems.
and finally I found that it's relative to the SVN version I use.
it always failed to `commit` when I use TortoiseSVN version is below 1.8.

I don't know whether it's because i am in a internal network, I set the proxy, but it's still doesn't work. And this problem occurs both IDEA 12, 13.

so my question is anyone has same problem and how to solve it?
it's that Idea's bug or I need to configure the IDEA somewhere?

Thanks if somebody can help.

### Update:

I make a mistake. it works on only at svn 1.8,
for some reason sometimes i can only use svn 1.6 format,so i want to know why.

### The errors:

> SVN: commit request failed on `xxxxx` SVN: Operation timed out

Comment: What errors do you get? Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check out the project in correct format (1.7/1.8) ? And what is the error you are getting?